# Newton's method to solve implicit Runge-Kutta-method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm having a bit of a problem to solve an initial value problem by employing an implicit s-step Runge-Kutta method (and Newton's method). More precisely, I don't know how to employ Newton's method in this case. The initial value problem is pretty standard:

\begin{equation*}
y'(t) = f(t,y(t)), \quad y(t_0) = 0 =:y_0 \in \mathbb R^n, \quad f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R.
\end{equation*}
I'm also given $f'$ (the Jacobian of $f$)  and a discrete time grid $(t_0, \ldots, t_N)$ as well as the Butcher tableau regarding the Runge-Kutta method:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|c}  
c&A \\ \hline
&b  
\end{array}, \quad c \in \mathbb R^s, A \in \mathbb R^{s,s}, b \in \mathbb R^{1,s}.
\end{equation*}
Now I have to calculate the $k_i$ such that I can calculate $y_1 = y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^s b_ik_i.$ Since $A$ isn't necessarily a strictly lower triangular matrix, or even triangular at all, I have to solve a set of linear (or nonlinear) equations to calculate the $k_i$. So my first system of equations reads as follows:
\begin{align*}
k_1 &= f\left(t_0+c_1h,y_0+h\sum_{i=1}^sa_{1i}k_1\right)\\
k_2 &= f\left(t_0+c_2h,y_0+h\sum_{i=1}^sa_{2i}k_1\right)\\
&\,\,\vdots\\
k_s &= f\left(t_0+c_sh,y_0+h\sum_{i=1}^sa_{si}k_1\right),
\end{align*}
with $h := t_1 - t_0$. To solve this system, I have to use Newton's method. That's the part where I'm stuck. My current idea is this: Let $K := (k_1, \ldots, k_s)^T$ and define
\begin{equation*}
F : \mathbb R^{s\cdot n} \to \mathbb R^{s \cdot n}, \quad K \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
f_1(K)-k_1\\
f_2(K)-k_2\\
\vdots\\
f_s(K)-k_s
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
f_j(K) = f\left(t_0+c_jh,y_0+h\sum_{i=1}^s a_{ji}k_i \right).
\end{equation*}
Then I would start, as suggested in the assignment, with $k_1 = k_2 = \ldots = k_s = 0$ to find a $\tilde{K}$ such that $F(\tilde{K}) = 0$ via Newton's method, which would solve the system of equations and thusly allow me to calculate $y_1$. Then I could do the same for $y_2, y_3, \ldots$. I do however need the Jacobian of my function $F$ and I'm inadept to calculate it simply given the Jacobian of $ f $ I'm presented with.

I suppose it'd look like this:
\begin{align*}
J_F(K) &= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1-k_1}{\partial k_1} (K)& 
\frac{\partial f_1-k_1}{\partial k_2} (K)& \cdots & 
\frac{\partial f_1-k_1}{\partial k_s}(K)\\
\frac{\partial f_2-k_2}{\partial k_1}(K)& 
\frac{\partial f_2-k_2}{\partial k_2} (K) & \cdots & 
\frac{\partial f_2-k_2}{\partial k_s}(K)\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_s-k_s}{\partial k_1} (K)& \cdots & &
\frac{\partial f_s-k_s}{\partial k_s}(K)
\end{pmatrix}
\\&= \begin{pmatrix}
\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial k_1}-1\right) (K)& 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial k_2} (K)& \cdots & 
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial k_s}(K)\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial k_1}(K)& 
\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial k_2}-1\right) (K) & \cdots & 
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial k_s}(K)\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial k_1} (K)& \cdots & &
\left(\frac{\partial f_s}{\partial k_s}-1\right)(K)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Note: I do not know which function I'm given, nor do I know which Runge-Kutta method I actually have to solve. I'm writing a program in MATLAB and get these information fed as part of the assignment. Moreover, the solving of the problem is slightly urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial k_j}=\frac{∂f}{∂y}a_{ij}
$$